# Finding closest related words using word2vec

Tags: python, machine-learning, word2vec

My goal is to find most relevant words given set of keywords using word2vec. For example, if I have a set of words `[girl, kite, beach]`, I would like relevants words to be output from word2vec: `[flying, swimming, swimsuit...]`

I understand that word2vec will vectorize a word based on the context of surround words. So what I did, was use the following function:

`most_similar_cosmul([girl, kite, beach])`

However, it seems to give out words not very related to the set of keywords:

```
['charade', 0.30288437008857727]
['kinetic', 0.3002534508705139]
['shells', 0.29911646246910095]
['kites', 0.2987399995326996]
['7-9', 0.2962781488895416]
['showering', 0.2953910827636719]
['caribbean', 0.294752299785614]
['hide-and-go-seek', 0.2939240336418152]
['turbine', 0.2933803200721741]
['teenybopper', 0.29288050532341003]
['rock-paper-scissors', 0.2928623557090759]
['noisemaker', 0.2927709221839905]
['scuba-diving', 0.29180505871772766]
['yachting', 0.2907838821411133]
['cherub', 0.2905363440513611]
['swimmingpool', 0.290039986371994]
['coastline', 0.28998953104019165]
['Dinosaur', 0.2893030643463135]
['flip-flops', 0.28784963488578796]
['guardsman', 0.28728148341178894]
['frisbee', 0.28687697649002075]
['baltic', 0.28405341506004333]
['deprive', 0.28401875495910645]
['surfs', 0.2839275300502777]
['outwear', 0.28376665711402893]
['diverstiy', 0.28341981768608093]
['mid-air', 0.2829524278640747]
['kickboard', 0.28234976530075073]
['tanning', 0.281939834356308]
['admiration', 0.28123530745506287]
['Mediterranean', 0.281186580657959]
['cycles', 0.2807052433490753]
['teepee', 0.28070521354675293]
['progeny', 0.2775532305240631]
['starfish', 0.2775339186191559]
['romp', 0.27724218368530273]
['pebbles', 0.2771730124950409]
['waterpark', 0.27666303515434265]
['tarzan', 0.276429146528244]
['lighthouse', 0.2756190896034241]
['captain', 0.2755546569824219]
['popsicle', 0.2753356397151947]
['Pohoda', 0.2751699686050415]
['angelic', 0.27499720454216003]
['african-american', 0.27493417263031006]
['dam', 0.2747344970703125]
['aura', 0.2740659713745117]
['Caribbean', 0.2739778757095337]
['necking', 0.27346789836883545]
['sleight', 0.2733519673347473]
```

This is the code I used to train word2vec

```
def train(data_filepath, epochs=300, num_features=300, min_word_count=2, context_size=7, downsampling=1e-3, seed=1,
  ckpt_filename=None):
  """
    Train word2vec model
    data_filepath path of the data file in csv format
    :param epochs: number of times to train
    :param num_features: increase to improve generality, more computationally expensive to train
    :param min_word_count: minimum frequency of word. Word with lower frequency will not be included in training data
    :param context_size: context window length
    :param downsampling: reduce frequency for frequent keywords
    :param seed: make results reproducible for random generator. Same seed means, after training model produces same results.

    :returns path of the checkpoint after training
  """

  if ckpt_filename == None:
    data_base_filename = os.path.basename(data_filepath)
    data_filename = os.path.splitext(data_base_filename)[0]
    ckpt_filename = data_filename + ".wv.ckpt"

  num_workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
  logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
  nltk.download("punkt")
  nltk.download("stopwords")
  print("Training %s ..." % data_filepath)
  sentences = _get_sentences(data_filepath)

  word2vec = w2v.Word2Vec(
    sg=1,
    seed=seed,
    workers=num_workers,
    size=num_features,
    min_count=min_word_count,
    window=context_size,
    sample=downsampling
  )

  word2vec.build_vocab(sentences)
  print("Word2vec vocab length: %d" % len(word2vec.wv.vocab))
  word2vec.train(sentences, total_examples=len(sentences), epochs=epochs)
  return _save_ckpt(word2vec, ckpt_filename)

def _save_ckpt(model, ckpt_filename):
  if not os.path.exists("checkpoints"):
    os.makedirs("checkpoints")
  ckpt_filepath = os.path.join("checkpoints", ckpt_filename)
  model.save(ckpt_filepath)
  return ckpt_filepath

def _get_sentences(data_filename):
  print("Found Data:")
  sentences = []
  print("Reading '{0}'...".format(data_filename))
  with codecs.open(data_filename, "r") as data_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(data_file)
    for row in reader:
      sentences.append(ast.literal_eval((row["highscores"])))
  print("There are {0} sentences".format(len(sentences)))
  return sentences

if __name__ == "__main__":
  import argparse
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Train Word2vec model')
  parser.add_argument('data_filepath',
                      help='path to training CSV file.')
  args = parser.parse_args()
  data_filepath = args.data_filepath
  train(data_filepath)
```

This is a sample of training data used for word2vec:

```
22751473,"[""lover"", ""sweetheart"", ""couple"", ""dietary"", ""meal""]"
28738542,"[""mallotus"", ""villosus"", ""shishamo"", ""smelt"", ""dried"", ""fish"", ""spirinchus"", ""lanceolatus""]"
25163686,"[""Snow"", ""Removal"", ""snow"", ""clearing"", ""female"", ""females"", ""woman"", ""women"", ""blower"", ""snowy"", ""road"", ""operate""]"
32837025,"[""milk"", ""breakfast"", ""drink"", ""cereal"", ""eating""]"
23828321,"[""jogging"", ""female"", ""females"", ""lady"", ""woman"", ""women"", ""running"", ""person""]"
22874156,"[""lover"", ""sweetheart"", ""heterosexual"", ""couple"", ""man"", ""and"", ""woman"", ""consulting"", ""hear"", ""listening""]
```

For prediction, I simply used the following function for a set of keywords:

```
most_similar_cosmul
```

I was wondering whether it is possible to find relevant keywords with word2vec. If it is not, then what machine learning model would be more suitable for this. Any insights would be very helpful

Comment: Please specify what technique you have used to implement word2vec & other related info?

Comment: I have added the code for training and training data for word2vec

Answer (score 1):

When supplying multiple positive-word examples, like `['girl', 'kite', 'beach']`, to `most_similar()`/`most_similar_cosmul()`, the vectors for those words will be averaged-together first, then a list of words most similar to the average returned. Those might not be as obviously related to any one of the words than a simple check of a single word. So:

When you try `most_similar()` (or `most_similar_cosmul()`) on a single word, what kind of results do you get? Are they words that seem related to the input word, in the way that you care about?

If not, you have deeper problems in your setup that should be fixed before trying a multi-word similarity.

Word2Vec gets its usual results from (1) lots of training data; and (2) natural-language sentences. With enough data, a typical number of `epochs` training-passes (and thus the default) is 5. You can sometimes, somewhat make up for less data by using more epoch iterations, or a smaller vector `size`, but not always.

It's not clear how much data you have. Also, your example rows aren't real natural-language sentences – they appear to have had some other preprocessing/reordering applied. That may be hurting rather than helping.

Word-vectors often improve by throwing away *more* low-frequency words (increasing `min_count` above the default 5, rather than reducing it to 2.) Low-frequency words don't have enough examples to get good vectors – and the few examples they have, even if repeated with many iterations, tend to be idiosyncratic examples of the words' usage, *not* the generalizable broad representations that you'd get from many varied examples. And by keeping these doomed-to-be-weak words still in the training-data, the training of other more-frequent words is interfered with. (When you get a word that you don't think belongs in a most-similar ranking, it may be a rare-word that, given its its few occurrence contexts, found its way to those coordinates as the least-bad location among plenty of other unhelpful coordinates.)

If you do get good results from single-word checks, but not from the average-of-multiple-words, the results might improve with more and better data, or adjusted training parameters – but to achieve that you'd need to more rigorously define what you consider good results. (Your existing list doesn't look that bad to me: it includes many words related to sun/sand/beach activities.)

On the other hand, your expectations of Word2Vec may be too high: it may not be that the average of `['girl', 'kite', 'beach']` is necessarily closed to those desired words, compared to the individual words themselves, or that may only be achievable with lots of dataset/parameter tweaking.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. To answer some of the questions above:

1. When I call most_similar or most_similar_cosmul, on the above words, indeed I do get some words related to the individual input words, but not many words "connect" or "show relationship" of set of keywords. I assumed that if "kite", "girl", "flying" are in the same row a lot, then the probability of most_similar the word "flying" should increase given "girl", "kite".

2. For training data I have about 410,000 rows.

3. Indeed my results of most_similar words is better for individual than group

Comment: Ah, I see. 410,000 rows of 5-to-10 words-per-row is still only ~2-to-4 million words, which is kind of small for word2vec. And your rows don't look like real natural-language sentences, which may further impair the usual word2vec-arranging. And the issues with low-frequency words causing problems, and the average-of-many-words not necessarily finding what you intend, remain. But I do think (1) more data; (2) more tuning of metaparameters; (3) other forms of 'nearness' (like perhaps words most close-to-each, rather than close-to-the-average, etc) may each get you closer to your goal. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just one last question. Is sentence format really important for word2vec. Because as I remember word2vec works with a neural network and window. If it's RNN then the order of words (like in a sentence) would be important. Shouldn't it still work as it intended if I just give it a list of tags, instead of sentence?

Comment: Order of words is important, because it affects which words are in each others' windows (unless the window is so large it includes the whole 'sentence', which may not be optimal). It might work ok with "sequences of tokens kind of like sentences" – certainly people have used word2vec to create vectors from non-natural-language data. But whether it works as well, if words have been reordered/filtered/duplicated, or some 'connecting' words have been eliminated, isn't clear. (It might work better, or worse – but it's no longer the same natural-language data on which its usefulness is best known.)